# How to swap one value with next value in Python?

Tags: python

For example, I have a list: `[25,3,26,27,56]`.

I want to write a function that swap the number 27 with next value. In the example above, is swapping the position between 27 and 56.

But actually I don't know what the values exactly are in a list.

So my question is, how to express 'the next value'? I tried to use index, but I'm not sure how to express it. and, I know how to replace a number by another number, but how to swap two numbers in a list(the number 27 is known, swap 27 with next value, but I don't know what next value is)?

Comment: can you post some code on what you have tried so far - even if it is the code which replaces one list item with another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can swap the values in a single line like this

```
myList = [25,3,26,27,56]
myList[3], myList[4] = myList[4], myList[3]
print myList
```

**Output**

```
[25, 3, 26, 56, 27]
```

If the values in the right hand side are separated by commas, python treats them as a tuple and unpacks them one by one to the left hand side variables. In this case, it picks the values of `myList[4]` and `myList[3]` and assigns them to `myList[3]` and `myList[4]` respectively.

**Edit:** If you want to swap each and every successive elements, you can do this

```
myList = [25,3,26,27,56]
for i in range(0, len(myList) - 1, 2):
    myList[i], myList[i + 1] = myList[i + 1], myList[i]
print myList
```

**Output**

```
[3, 25, 27, 26, 56]
```

If you specifically want to swap 27 with the next number, you can use `index` function to get the index of `27` and swap like this

```
myList = [25,3,26,27,56]
idx = myList.index(27)
if idx == len(myList) - 1: # If 27 is the last element, swap with the previous
    myList[idx], myList[idx - 1] = myList[idx - 1], myList[idx]
else:
    myList[idx], myList[idx + 1] = myList[idx + 1], myList[idx]
print myList
```

Comment: I don't know the exact position of 27....I was given 1 to 28 in the question, but I wasn't given the order of these numbers.

Comment: the last one helps a lot!Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manipulate a chunk of a list, a slice assignment is a nice way to do it

```
>>> foo = [25, 3, 26, 27, 56]
>>> i = foo.index(27)
>>> foo[i: i+2] = foo[i+2: i-1: -1]
>>> foo
[25, 3, 26, 56, 27]
```

You could also use

```
>>> foo[i: i+2] = reversed(foo[i: i+2])
```

or

```
>>> foo[i: i+2] = foo[i+1], foo[i]
```

Comment: typo in last foo, should be `foo[i]`

Comment: or `foo[i: i+2] = foo[i: i+2][::-1]`